# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addHelper')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWb5c.jpg)This is my Package.json I am getting the addHelper issue in my metro of @babel This is my error.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.15",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.10",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.2.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^3.2.0",
    "file-extension": "^4.0.5",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.37",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "^2.8.2",
    
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }, 
  "overrides": {
    "@babel/traverse": "7.22.6"
  }
```

I am unable to solve the issue as i tried to solve as suggested in my metro in the @bable index.js file but every time i solve the issue and get another addHelper issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I tried to run my application i got this "error: index.js: undefined: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addHelper')" as an error and and the emulator show the error as uploaded in the picture.

Comment: I have resolve it by simply updating the "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0", to a newer version in my case the new version is ""metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.68.0",'